# how to add jquery and bootstrap add on to spring roo

Tags: spring-roo, add-on

I created one spring roo project which has default dojo. But I want to add jquery and bootstrap add-on. Could you please help me on the steps to add the add-on and install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This features are supported by [gvNIX project](http://www.gvnix.org/). Look at this [demo](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app) ([on-line](http://petclinic-gvnix.rhcloud.com/login)).

Good luck!

Comment: If this answerer your question, please, click at check mark. This way everybody can identify it as the right answer. Thank you.